# RxJava2: Apply a given scheduler to whole stream?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an `Observable<Item>` **(A)** that emits its items every time a `PublishSubject<Item>` **(B)** has a new `Item`.

**A** is then used such as `A.subscribeOn(computationScheduler).observeOn(mainThread)`

---

Goal: Have full stream from **A** do its work on the computation-scheduler, and then consume the result on the main-thread.

Actual: Depending on where **B** is observed, the whole stream will run on different schedulers accordingly. In below example -- on the main-thread, even through the `.subscribeOn()` call.

**How can I 'force' the full stream from A to do its work on a given scheduler, and dispatch results on another?** 
*A.compose() doesnt do the trick.*

---

Actual code:

```
class SomeClass

private final PublishSubject<ExerciseQueryOptions> queryOptionsPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

@NonNull
@Override
public Observable<List<ExerciseViewModel>> call() {
    return queryOptionsPublishSubject
            .startWith(createQueryOptions())
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .flatMap(new Function<ExerciseQueryOptions, ObservableSource<List<ExerciseViewModel>>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<List<ExerciseViewModel>> apply(ExerciseQueryOptions queryOptions) throws Exception {
                    //This is the code I want to run on a given scheduler,
                    //Supplied by the code that calls this .call() method.
                    return datastore.queryAll(ExerciseModel.class, true)
                            .map(transformer);                      
                }
            });
}

//Other class
SomeClass A; 

A.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).observeOn(AndroidScheduers.mainThread())
.subcribe(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element of your `flatMap` must be on the scheduler:

```
                return datastore.queryAll(ExerciseModel.class, true)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .map(transformer);
```

You also need to have the whole stream subscribe on the computation scheduler, otherwise the initial subscription will run on the current thread.